# Mudar a cor de um elemento <progress> do HTML5

Tags: html, css, html5

Eu preciso mudar a cor de uma *progress bar* (tag `<progress>` do HTML5) com CSS. A padrão do Google Chrome é assim:

[image: Barra padrão atual do google chrome]

Mas se eu tento estilizar com css fica assim:

[image: Minha tentativa]

Como posso deixar o fundo (a parte cinza e branca das progress bar acima) de uma cor e a porcentagem (as partes azuis e cinzas das mesmas) de outra cor? Não precisa ser listradas com muitas coisas, apenas queria mudar a cor. O que eu desejo é mais ou menos assim:

[image: aparência desejada]

segue o código HTML:

```
 <progress  style="left: -162px; position: relative; z-index: 1; height: 26px; width: 160px" id="progress" min="0" step="32" max="158" value="50" ></progress>
```

css:

```
 progress {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid #808080 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #C0C0C0; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #C0C0C0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #C0C0C0;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Olá, podes colocar o script ajax ?

Comment: Samir sem ver o seu código é dificil ajudar. Coloque o código aqui pf.

Comment: Na verdade é um simples javascript puro, em que eu vou fazer como um sistema de votação com a barra, o script não interfere nada.

Comment: ok, vou editar.

Comment: Experimenta border: 2px solid #cor; em vez daquela expressao que ai esta.

Comment: O objectivo é o fundo dessa div certo ? Coloca-la com fundo verde lima ?

Comment: Oi Samir. Em vez de inserir o "solucionado" na pergunta, marque a resposta correta clicando no símbolo de "ticar" que fica perto da pontuação da resposta. Pode ser sua própria resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de uma boa pesquisada, boa mesmo, achei uma solução.

Para o `value` da barra basta acresentar no `css`:

```
#progresss::-webkit-progress-value {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
}
```

E para o fundo:

```
 #progresss[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
   background: #eeeeee;
   border-radius: 2px;
 }
```

E para tamanho, bordas, localização na página, posição e etc. Usa-se o próprio `progress{}` mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Para remover a aparência padrão:

```
progress {
    display:block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Para definir a nova aparência do fundo:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {  
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Para definir a nova aparência do valor:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 50px;
    background:orange;
}
```

[Fonte](http://www.desarrollolibre.net/blog/tema/70/html5-css-js/el-elemento-progress-bar-html5#.VP5YwfnF-So)